# Calling the Facebook API from desktop javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm working on a plugin to enable a mailclient to access a users Facebook Inbox. I know I need to request an access token with extended permissions. The thing is: I have no Idea how to do that.

The plugin needs to be written in javascript. I have managed to open a webbrowser to the required URL but I have no idea, how to extract the access token from the webbrowser, in order to use it in the rest of my script.

Is there any way this can be achieved, or do i need to use different technology?

Answer (score 0):

To get an access token you need to first create a Facebook application. To do it, add the developer application to your Facebook profile.
http://developers.facebook.com/

Then the user will need to grant access to your application. 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/